# Send data to Airtables through a POST request with a json body

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, airtable

Im trying to send data to Airtables using its REST APIs based on the documentation. The part Im stuck is adding the parameters. It throws me an error saying "**Invalid request: parameter validation failed. Check your request data**".

The Curl according to the doc as bellow.

[image]

My partially done code as bellow.

```
    let table_name = "Diet%20Plan"
    let base_id = "appmrzybooFj9mFVF"
    let token = "SomeID"
      
      // prepare json data
    let json: [String: String] = ["Food Type": "Minseee",
                                     "Person Name": "Rabiit Con"]
    
    // create the url with URL
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.airtable.com/v0/\(base_id)/\(table_name)")! // change server url accordingly

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue( "Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            return
        }
        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            print(responseJSON) //Code after Successfull POST Request
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, request body seems to be made like:

```json
{"Person Name":"Rabiit Con","Food Type":"Minseee"}
```

What it needs to be sending is:

```json
"fields": {
   "Person Name":"Rabiit Con",
   "Food Type":"Minseee"
}
```

Try

```swift
let json: [String: Any] = ["fields": ["Food Type": "Minseee",
                                      "Person Name": "Rabiit Con"]]

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
```

Comment: Using structs could be a better approach